# Views pager uses wrong URL when using views_embed_view()

Tags: 7, views, ajax

I have a custom AJAX app which allows the user to filter some nodes, which uses a View. By custom AJAX app, I mean that this is **not** just a view with AJAX enabled.

The user accesses `/reports` which includes the output of `views_embed_view()`. An AJAX-enabled browser interacts with the page, resulting in an AJAX call to `/reports/ajax` to fetch just the results and save a full page re-load.

It all works, **except** that the results returned by the View in this case use `/reports/ajax` as the base URL for the pager (because that's the path used to invoke the custom AJAX controller), which means that when the user clicks one, they get a page of AJAX response.

I would like to train Views to use a different URL (i.e. `/reports`) for pager requests. Beyond a `str_replace` in the output of `views_embed_view()`, is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Manually set `$_GET['q']` to the appropriate value before calling `views_get_view()`.

Views' pager uses the standard Drupal pager from `includes/pager.inc` which uses this request variable:

```
function theme_pager_link($variables) {
  // (... code omitted here ...)

  // @todo l() cannot be used here, since it adds an 'active' class based on the                                       
  //   path only (which is always the current path for pager links). Apparently,                                       
  //   none of the pager links is active at any time - but it should still be                                          
  //   possible to use l() here.                                                                                       
  // @see http://drupal.org/node/1410574                                                                               
  $attributes['href'] = url($_GET['q'], array('query' => $query));                                                     
  return '<a' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . check_plain($text) . '</a>';   
}
```